# SP2010 Search shows no results on custom list

Tags: 2010

I have a custom "FAQ" list in SharePoint 2010 as an Item content type. When I try using the search bar with key words in the custom list items, it does not show up in the results page. I have the crawler working on rest of the site, however, it is not working on this specific custom list. Any suggestions on where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things to check:

- On your FAQ list, go into List Settings > Advanced Settings, and make sure that the "Allow items from this list to appear in search results?" option is set to YES.
- If you have access, make sure that an incremental or full crawl has run successfully since your FAQ items were added. If not, you can force a crawl via the search application in Central Admin.
- If you have access to it, go into the Managed Properties for the search application and make sure that your custom properties (Question, Answer, FAQ-Category, whatever) are being crawled. You'll also want to make sure there aren't any crawl rules excluding the list items for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. The search box starting working randomly... and I'm perfectly fine with that!